# What does "power of something" mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, articles, zero-article

I would like to comprehend the meaning of the phrase *power of art*. An example, for some context:

> You are a person that appreciates the ***power of art***.

How do I use this phrase *"The power of art"* and when?

Answer (score 1):

**You appreciate the power of *X*** implies two statements:

1. *X* is powerful.
2. You appreciate this power.

*X* can be pretty much anything, figurative or literal, and you can use this kind of construction very freely:

- The power of television came to be vital in the 1950s
- The ancient Greeks understood the power of rhetoric.
- "The power of love / a force from above" (song lyric from [Frankie Goes to Hollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_Love_(Frankie_Goes_to_Hollywood_song)))
- "The power of love is a curious thing / make one man weep, another man sing" (song lyric from [Huey Lewis and the News](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_Love_(Huey_Lewis_and_the_News_song)))
- Don't underestimate the power of this engine (mechanical power)
- Don't underestimate the power of advertising (commercial or political power)
- Don't underestimate the power of the King's Regiment (military power)
- Don't underestimate the power of persuasion (personal power)

Comment: "The power of love, a force from above" - Lyric from Frankie Goes To Hollywood

Comment: @MikeBrockington many thanks!  Corrected